# On Mac OSX 10.8.4 where can I find the Go installation?

Tags: macos, go

I'm following [this online book](http://www.golang-book.com/2) in my path to learn Go during the weekends.

I've tried running the `go help gopath` command it just returns example paths and how they relate to each other in packages and source directories - it's doesn't actually say where I can find the go folder.

The book specifically mentions:

> First create a new folder where we can store our program. The
>   installer you used in chapter 1 created a folder in your home
>   directory named Go. Create a folder named
>   ~/Go/src/golang-book/chapter2. (Where ~ means your home directory)
>   From the terminal you can do this by entering the following commands:

I used the default installer on the Go homepage, so assume that everything installed in the default folder the installer comes with.

If I `cd` in terminal to the `~/` folder and then use `ls`, there is no `/Go` folder.

How can I find this folder in order to follow the online book properly? I'm assuming he's using this folder structure for a reason and would rather not deviate and learn how packages work, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instructions say:

> Create a folder named ~/Go/src/golang-book/chapter2

I interpret that to mean that **YOU** create the folder named "`~/Go/src/golang-book/chapter2`".  The installer doesn't create this, but you can.

E.G. in your Terminal:

```
mkdir ~/Go
mkdir ~/Go/src
mkdir ~/Go/src/golang-book
mkdir ~/Go/src/golang-book/chapter2
```

Comment: Or `mkdir -p ~/Go/src/golang-book/chapter2`.

Comment: I understood it to mean Go would create the `~/Go/src/` folder upon installation. I'll do it manually then, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

The command `go help gopath` outputs a bunch of useful info.  But also this command:

`go env GOPATH`

This will print your go directory.

When I installed Go with `brew` using `brew install go`, it was installed to my home dir: `~/go`